# Match a directory name at all levels of a file tree with Ant glob pattern

Tags: ant, jestjs, glob

Is there a way to match all directories of a specific name using an Ant glob pattern?

If I have the following tree for example:

```
> lib
    > __mocks__
    > helpers
        > __mocks__
    > middleware
        > __mocks__
```

I'd like to match `lib/__mocks__`, `lib/helpers/__mocks__`, and `lib/middleware/__mocks__` with a single pattern.

Comment: `**` will recurse through any number of subdirectories. Try the pattern `lib/**/__mocks__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using this glob: `lib/**/__mocks__/**`